# SmartTV IP with SSDP on WP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

```
 request.AppendLine("M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1");

 request.AppendLine("HOST: " + SSDP_IP + ":" + SSDP_PORT);

 request.AppendLine("MAN: \"ssdp:discover\"");

 request.AppendLine("MX: 3");

 request.AppendLine("ST: ssdp:all");

 request.AppendLine();
```

Hi Everybody , I am trying to get smart TVs' IP adress which are connected to my wifi ,

As usual i use 
SSDP_IP:239.255.255.250 
SSDP_PORT:1900 , 
and i am using ssdp query however i can just query ssdp:all , I searched on web however i couldnt find what i want , does anybody know how to query my smart TVs ?

Thank you

Answer (score -2):

This will give you some tips http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/art00030/index.html

It would be great if you upload your c# project as open source...I am quite curious about what you are doing.

Comment: It is not good to add just links since they may go dead at anytime,  but add the actual code suggestion/solution